# Rigorous explanation for a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am looking to answer in fundamental rigour the following, but I'm unsure how to explain a crucial step:

> Let $N^{(1)}(t), N^{(2)}(t)$ be independent Poisson processes with respective rates $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Let $T=\inf\{t: N^{(1)}(t)>0\}$ and $X=N^{(2)}(T)$. What is $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(T)]?$

My idea is this.

See that $T\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$,  $\sigma(T)=\sigma(\{T\geqslant t\}:t\geqslant 0)$, and that $X\mathbb{1}_{\{T=t\}}\sim \text{Po}(\lambda_2t)$, where $\mathbb{1}_\cdot$ is an indicator function.

Then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{1}_{\{T\geqslant t\}}]& =  \sum_{x=0}^\infty x \mathbb{P}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{T\geqslant t\}}=x) \\
& =\sum_{x=0}^\infty x \int_t^\infty \mathbb{P}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{T= s\}}=x) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 s}ds
\end{align}

and after an application of Fubini and using
$$
\sum_{x=0}^\infty x\mathbb{P}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{T= s\}}=x)= \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{1}_{\{T=s\}}]=\lambda_2 s
$$
the result follows straightforwardly to show that $\lambda_2 T$ is the answer almost surely.

However I am not sure if it is correct to say
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{T\geqslant t\}}=x)= \int_t^\infty \mathbb{P}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{T= s\}}=x) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 s}ds
$$
or how I could explain it rigorously. I see the issue that $\{T=t\}$ is null so technically it doesn't work.

Any input would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
\begin{align}
N^{(i)}(t)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{\tau^{(i)}_k\le t\}}\,,\\
N^{(2)}(T)&=N^{(2)}(\tau^{(1)}_1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{\tau^{(2)}_k\le \tau^{(1)}_1\}}\,
\end{align}
where $\tau^{(i)}$ are the jump times of $N^{(i)}\,.$

Then use the following standard

***Lemma.*** *When $U,V$ are two independent random variables and $f:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ a Borel function then
$$
\mathbb E[f(U,V)|\sigma(V)]=\mathbb E[f(U,v)]\Big|_{v=V}\,.
$$*
This lemma is shown by assuming first that $f$ is of the form $f(u,v)=g(u)h(v)$ (for which it is trivial) and then using a monotone class theorem to show it for general $f\ge 0\,.$

In your case $k$ is fixed but arbitrary and $U=\tau^{(2)}_k$ and $V=T=\tau^{(1)}_1$ and
$$f(U,V)=1_{\{\tau^{(2)}_k\le \tau^{(1)}_1\}}\,.$$ This gives
$$
\mathbb E\Big[1_{\{\tau^{(2)}_k\le T\}}\,\Big|\,\sigma(T)\Big]=\mathbb P\Big\{\tau^{(2)}_k\le t\Big\}\Big|_{t=T}\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E\Big[N^{(2)}(T)\,\Big|\,\sigma(T)\Big]=\mathbb E\Big[\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1_{\{\tau^{(2)}\le t\}}\,\Big]\Big|_{t=T}=\mathbb E\Big[N^{(2)}(t)\Big]\,\Big|_{t=T}=\lambda_2T\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this!  This makes sense to me, but I am wondering if you can reference a proof of the lemma you claim? I think I'm fine with all of it except to show how the sigma algebra generated by all suitable $f=gh$ is the sigma algebra generated by all $f(u,v)$.

Comment: @jcneek Some better experts here on MSE prefer to use a $\pi$-$\lambda$-theorem. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2159700/949989). When you search for these buzzwords combined with conditional expectation you may find that Lemma.

Comment: @jcneek [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73363/949989) looks exactly like what we were looking for.